# Special characters should not be used continually

Tags: javascript, regex

I'm creating regex for URL validation. Somehow i have validated Url as i need but my requirement was after the domain name `https://asasas.com/` special character should not allow to be continually. Wanted to know how to restrict that?
**My regex**
**Part 1 :** `(https?:\/\/(?:www\.|(?!www))[a-zA-Z0-9][a-zA-Z0-9-]+[a-zA-Z0-9]\.[^\s]{2,}|www\.[a-zA-Z0-9][a-zA-Z0-9-]+[a-zA-Z0-9]\.[^\s]{2,}|https?:\/\/(?:www\.|(?!www))[a-zA-Z0-9]+\.[^\s]{2,}|www\.[a-zA-Z0-9]+\.[^\s]{2,})`
**Part 2:** `[/]+[a-zA-Z0-9~@#$`!^%*;'&()<>_+=[]{}|\,.?: -]+.(?:jpg$|gif$|png$|jpeg$)/`

**Part 1** regex to validate URL and **Part 2** regex to validate string that it should end with .JPG or .PNG or .JPEG or .GIF

My requirement was it should not allow?
1) https://ssas.com//////////////////////////sds.png
2) https://ssas.com/sds//@#$%/j^&&*///.png

**Success case:**
each and every special character it should have word or number
1) https://ssas.com/sds/sdsd/s#df^ggasa/dadsa.png

Comment: `/` and `@` appear together in your example

Comment: What are you defining as a special character here?  Easiest solution: Add a negative lookahead which asserts that two or more special characters do not occur in succession.

Comment: @CinCout-ReinstateMonica It my mistake. Can you check again

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen except alphanumeric. Can you tell me how to do it?

Comment: Unfortunately, your current regex is in a messy state, and therefore I'm reluctant to even use it to post an answer.

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen I have updated my question above can you please check it?

Comment: Add something like `(?!.*[~@#$!^%*;'&()<>_+=[]{}|\,.?: -].*[~@#$!^%*;'&()<>_+=[]{}|\,.?: -])` to the start of the pattern.  I can't venture a formal answer, because your pattern is too complex/messy and I don't understand it.

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen What i am trying to do is that? I have to validate the image URL. 
1) The URL should end with (JPG or .PNG or .JPEG or .GIF).
2) The URL should not have a special character continually as shown in the example above.
Ans this is my requirement

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of validating the whole url with a regex, you could first validate the url using [URL](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/URL).

Then you could check if the protocol starts with http and use a pattern to check if the string after the [origin](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/URL/origin) ends with one of the allowed extensions and that the string does not contain to consecutive chars which you would consider special.

If you want to get a case insensitive match, you could make use of the `/i` flag.

The pattern consists of 2 assertions (non consuming)

```
^(?=.*\.(?:jpe?g|png|gif)$)(?!.*[/~@#$!^%*;'&()<>_+=\[\]{}|\,.?:-][/~@#$!^%*;'&()<>_+=\[\]{}|\,.?:-])
```

In parts

- `^` Start of string
- `(?=` Positive lookahead, assert what is on the right is

  - `.*\.(?:jpe?g|png|gif)$` Match any of the listed at the end `$` of string
- `)` Close lookahead
- `(?!` Negative lookahead, assert what is on the right is not

  - `.*` Match any char except a newline 0+ times
  - `[/~@#$!^%*;'&()<>_+=\[\]{}|\,.?:-]` Match any of the listed
  - `[/~@#$!^%*;'&()<>_+=\[\]{}|\,.?:-]` Same as above
- `)` Close lookahead

[Regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/ZIfTSi/1)

```js
[
  "https://ssas.com//////////////////////////sds.png",
  "https://ssas.com/sds//@#$%/j^&&*///.png",
  "https://ssas.com/sds/sdsd/s#df^ggasa/dadsa.png"
].forEach(s => {
  let url = new URL(s);
  let secondPart = url.href.replace(url.origin, '');
  let pattern = /^(?=.*\.(?:jpe?g|png|gif)$)(?!.*[/~@#$!^%*;'&()<>_+=\[\]{}|,.?:-][/~@#$!^%*;'&()<>_+=\[\]{}|,.?:-])/i;
  if (
    url.protocol.startsWith("http") &&
    pattern.test(secondPart)) {
    console.log(s);
  }
})
```